# Symfony Translator is not generating cache message catalogue for default locale?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, symfony

I am trying to run a Symfony 2.6.4 application on the Google AppEngine which is translated to 5 languages.

Problem is that `cache:clear` command generates only message catalogues for all languages except default locale (sk) and then it tries to generate missing message catalogue on the fly. Problem is that Google AppEngine is read-only. Can anybody explain why it isn't generated on `cache:clear` in warmup stage?

app.yml

```
framework:
   default_locale: "sk"
   translator:
       fallback: "sk"

jms_i18n_routing:
   default_locale: sk
   locales: [cs, en, de, sk, ru]
   strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Cannot rename "vfs://root/temp/.../app/cache/prod/translations/catalogue.sk.php54e9b262334c93.83518975" to "/.../app/cache/prod/translations/catalogue.sk.php".") in base.html.twig at line 10.

Please, can anybody help me? I am trying to solve this for 3 days.

Comment: Of course I can solve it by using vfs:// stream wrapper for cache dir in AppKernel but it isn't the right solution because I will not able to use cache at all.

Comment: You should consider using gcs as your cache dir in AppKernel.

Comment: Yes but reading from bucket are Class A operations. What is the purpose of cache warmuping if it isn't generated completely? :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you meant by Class A operation. The first time you hit your app, the cache files will be generated and written to GCS. All subsequent requests will retrieve the cache files from GCS with transparent caching using memcache.

Comment: You are right, it works. But encountered another problem, that GAE for PHP is missing intl extension (so using twig localization extension are completely useless if you want to use locale other than en) so we ended with GAE managed vm and our own docker configuration.